# Can I use Monkeyrunner for testing my own APIs?

Tags: api, testing, monkeyrunner

I have an application, which is written on top of Android, and it uses BT, WiFi, NFC APIS from Android. This application will expose some APIs, which other users can use to create their own apps.But before exposing the APIs, I want to test them.Can i use Monkey runner for this?

Answer (score 1):

**monkeyrunner** doesn't know anything about APIs. It's main goal is to send events to the device or emulator, perhaps start some activities or take some screenshots, all from *outside* android code.